# How to understand Maven .m2 folder?

Tags: maven

version: apache-maven-3.6.3

(1) I'm confused about use maven `.m2` folder, I know when using the `mvn` command, Maven automatically creates the `.m2` folder. So, presumably related to executing the `mvn` command. Is it necessary to execute the command?

(2) When I config `settings.xml` 
`<localRepository>D:\mavenResource</localRepository>` ,It did download to disk D
But at the same time it still be downloaded to C:\Users\name.m2\repository,I don't know why. Can I delelt `.m2`? only use `D:\mavenResource`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Short answer is yes. .m2 folder / local repository of maven is where all your project artifacts, dependency jars are stored locally when you execute maven command (for eg. `mvn install`). You can have a look at the various build life cycles of maven from [Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

For more details on local Repository you can read [Introduction to Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)

2. Since you have not shared what you have modified within settings.xml, hope you have modified the `<localRepository>` tag as mentioned [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html). Just to verify you can delete your `.m2\repository` folder and re-run maven it should get downloaded in your new path.